# Making a gallery by a twentytwenty plugin

Tags: javascript, css, twentytwenty

I use a js plugin twentytwenty. It works. But I want to create a gallery by js. But when I try to apply display:block, images are not displayed correctly.

This is css of normal picture:

```
#twins_compare{
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top:2400px;
    left:15%;
    width:200px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id = "gallery">
<div id = "twins_compare" >
    <img src = "{{url_for('static', filename = 'images/twins_before.jpg')}}" >
    <img src = "{{url_for('static', filename = 'images/twins_after.jpg')}}" >
</div>
```

What I added:

```
#gallery div{
display:none;}
#gallery div:first-child{
display:block;}
```

Images look very strange:( Help, please.

Comment: Can you show the current output using a demo? Fork this if you need https://codepen.io/oloman/pen/jPOvrY

Comment: https://codepen.io/Katekot2001/pen/oKLrWJ

Comment: @ManojKumar are you here?

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the email. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OKbPWb So you want to wrap the current code inside a gallery and then use a slider to show different diff versions of two images?

Comment: yes,  and then I would like  to change dislpay block-none  by js

Comment: may be there is another way to make a gallery with 2020?

Comment: Is there any framework that you already use? Like Twitter Bootstrap or Foundation? Because it says that the plugin supports Foundation out of the box and you can see some of the Foundation gallery or slider examples.

Comment: no, well, but I think there is no such galleries with 2020:(